# Multiple Remote call made simultenously

Tags: apache-flex

I was making multiple remote calls and they are done sequentially and when I am getting a result event back it's triggering calls to all the methods with ResultEvent as an argument . I am supposed to receive the result event only in the method given inthe event listener but it's triggering calls to all the methods with ResultEvent as an argument .

Has anyone come across this kind of problem? Is there any workaround for it?

Comment: Can we see some code? It's hard to say anything without that.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the AsyncToken:

[Matching web service results to requests in Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468669/matching-web-service-results-to-requests-in-flex/469568#469568)